# Django: Allow user to access further only if she has submitted a form or has saved the model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The user passes through some forms just after signing up. There is logout link below every form page. I want to give the user further access to the site only if each of those forms have been saved. Now, in my case I have these models:

```
class Driving_plan(models.Model):
    plan = models.CharField (max_length=25, blank=False)
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    annual_fee = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=50.00)
    ....


class Payment_receipt(models.Model):
    driving_plans = models.ForeignKey(Driving_plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    end_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

When a user selects an instance of `Driving_plan`, this data is saved in the `Payment_receipt` model through this view:

```
@login_required
def passPlanPKView(request, pk):
    plan = Driving_plan.objects.get(pk = pk)
    Pay = Payment_receipt.objects.create(
        driving_plans=plan,
        user = request.user,
        start_date=datetime.date.today(),
        end_date= calcEnddate(plan),
        )
        return redirect('add_user_profile')
```

How do I apply this so that, if the user has got this model saved, redirect her to home. Otherwise, she must fill the form the next time she logs in?

In my case, when a user has not filled all the forms, she still is getting access by logging out; and when logging in she is straight into the home page. And the forms are left unsaved. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use models field to verified the user is submitted the necessary details or not . you can't track a form weather form submitted or not

Comment: How do I do the verification from models?

Comment: 1 st of all you said  " further access to the site only if each of those forms have been saved" . if a from save surely it create database record . suppose you have a form for user phone number add. if user submit the from the phone number wiil be save to that user object . now you query or that user object if phone number is available or not if available the user can processes an view or user will redirect to another view using redirect  function

Comment: Ok I got this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `.exists()`. I'm explaining with a new view, it's not needed to find similarities with the `passPlanPKView` in my question.

My view:

```
def homeview(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if not Payment_receipt.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('plan_select')
        if not Account.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('add_user_profile')
        if not Driving_license.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('add_license')
        if not Card_detail.objects.filter(user = request.user).exists():
            return redirect('add_card')
    return render(request, 'services/home.html')
```

Here, for an authenticated user, I'm querying each table/model to check whether the user has filled in data in that model through a form. If the use has just signed up and then logged out without filling any form, s/he is made to fill up those forms again.

I am checking for `Payment_receipt`, `Account`, `Driving_license`, `Card_detail` models one after another because, I require the new user to fill all the forms of these models sequentially just after signing up. If s/he logs out at any point while filling these forms, s/he will be redirected to the blank form after logging in.

If every model has data, and/or if the user is not authenticated or anonymous, s/he will be redirected to `home`.